# what type of password hash? possible mysql hash?

Tags: mysql, passwords, encryption

I was hosting a localhost site and can't find the decrypted password anywhere.

the encrypted password  => *85A7ADB64BFB8FAF77D233387448779C66D02A86

I think its mysql5 password but I can't decrypt it. Whats the decrypted-pass?

Answer (score 2):

You can't decrypt the password. MySQL passwords are encrypted using a one-way encryption function.

Per the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password):

> Encryption performed by PASSWORD() is one-way (not reversible). It is
>   not the same type of encryption as used for Unix passwords; for that,
>   use ENCRYPT().